# Text color changed in dark mode after update Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 to version 16.5.3

Tags: visual-studio, updates, textcolor

I've noticed that after update my VS Professional 2019 to v. 16.5.3 my code text colour changed.
It's partially hardly visible. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some bug in the VS installer.

Solution is switching mode to other and then back to dark mode.